# HTTPost setEntity equivalent in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an android application which communicates to the server through HTTP Post.

Here is the code and url_select is  "http://example.com/Padua/rest/messages/messagetodelete"

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_select);                   
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(message.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));               
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

This works well and I am able to get the message in the server. But when I try implementing this in iphone I am struck. I am not sure how to accomplish this. In Exact, the setentity part in NSMutalbleURLRequest

Below is the code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/Padua/rest/messages/messagetodelete"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/Padua/rest/messages/messagetodelete"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

//This is where I am getting confused. How to pass the messageid to the URL??         
[request setHTTPBody:messageid];
//This is where I am getting confused

NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageid
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request      delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Can any one please help me. I need to pass on the messageid in the URL itself in iOS as in Android.
Thanks and if you need any addtional info, I will provide you

Comment: Edit your question with message id regarding code how do you setup it?

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to set that. I need to embed the messageid in the URL.

Comment: Hi Timothy, Can you please tell me how did you figured it out? I am stuck to a similar situation.